# css animation fade in the text from top to bottom as eraser

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I need some help my aim is to achieve CSS animation on a div containing three lines of text and I want to switch between them where just one appears when moving from one line to another I want to make CSS animation like an eraser, what I'm understanding is I need a div like a mask with liner gradient white and transparent and try to move this mask bottom to top and the opposite when it's finish for each line

here as an example of what I want to achieve:
https://www.veed.io/view/d3f475f8-4407-40ce-8884-7d1faf0c941d?panel=share

and here is my attempt:

```css
.center {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* background: gray; */
}

.container {
  height: 45px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#test {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 55;
  background: linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%,
    rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%
  );
  animation: moveBottomToTop 2s linear infinite;
}

#test1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 55;
  background: linear-gradient(
    0deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 90%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%
  );
  animation: moveTopToBottom 2s linear infinite;
  animation-delay: 2.5s;
}

@keyframes moveBottomToTop {
  0% {
    visibility: hidden;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes moveTopToBottom {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div id="test1"></div>
    <p class="item">this is test text 1</p>
    <p class="item">this is test text 2</p>
    <p class="item">this is test text 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this is something can achieve in CSS so if not, please let me know how can achieve this my js